# Reset the program-counter (AKA instruction-pointer) to 0

Tags: c, compiler-construction, compilation, program-counter

I am trying to reset the program-counter (AKA instruction-pointer) to 0.

**I had expected the following C code to work (but it didn't):**

```
typedef void(*func)();
func reset = NULL;
reset();
```

**Here is the dis-assembly when using VS2013 compiler:**

```
mov  dword ptr[reset],0
mov  esi,esp
call dword ptr[reset]
```

I realize that this issue is not dictated by the C-language standard, but is rather a matter of specific compiler implementation. Nevertheless, I would expect it to work pretty much on every decent compiler.

What could a function-call be compiled into, besides setting the PC/IP to the address of that function?

Thanks

Comment: What did you expect that to do?  I expect that would crash.

Comment: @dohashi: No problem with the crash, but I would expect to see the PC register being set to 0 before the crash.

Comment: What do you observe in practice?

Comment: Standard way to perform this kind of action in assembler is `push 0; ret;` . IIRC, Some processors start at IP=0 at power on, or after an interrupt.

Comment: @dohashi: BTW, in a program where the code-section starts at memory address 0 (according to linker-settings), there is no harm in that, and the execution of the program can continue normally.

Comment: Your code causes my `$pc` to go to zero...

Comment: Might be worth mentioning what architecture/environment you're targeting

Comment: @merlin2011: Nice! Perhaps I should mention at this point that I have tested it with VS2013...

Comment: Just look at the disassembled machine code on the debugger. What does it do?

Comment: @DrewMcGowen: VS2013 over Intel i7. But as I mentioned in the question, I would expect it to work on every platform, regardless of the compiler in use or the underlying HW architecture.

Comment: There is no reason why a program should start at location=0. The hardware/architecture, or even the startup code / runtime can use any other location. [BTW: even the 6502 used a vectored interrupt to obtain its starting address at reset or power-up. Anything goes ...]

Comment: @hyde: As I mentioned in the question, I would expect it to work on every platform, regardless of the compiler in use or the underlying HW architecture. But in any case, I added the dis-assembly of the specific compiler that I've been testing it with. Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "expect it to work". Do you mean you expect the function to actually be called?

Comment: @DrewMcGowen: Sorry, good point. I would expect to see the PC/IP register being set to 0... Second though, it's actually specified in the title of the question, as well as in the opening statement...

Comment: @mafso: I do not see the PC/IP register being set to 0.

Comment: @barakmanos well, it *does* go to 0, but crashes as soon as the CPU tries to fetch an instruction at that address.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen: Oooooooooooops, just noticed exactly that. Question will be removed in a few minutes. Thank you all for your comments!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @DrewMcGowen: Second thought... It might serve as a useful piece of information here, so if you write-down your answer then I'll accept it.

Comment: @barakmanos updated my answer with that comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the hardware you're targeting, but it will probably compile to the same thing as any other function pointer call. It's also possible for the compiler to recognize the constant value given to `reset`, and optimize it as such. If nothing else, you could always do:

```
((void (*)())NULL)();
```

which basically casts `NULL` to a parameterless function of type `void`.

---

Whether or not the call succeeds is an entirely different matter: on most platforms using virtual memory, the kernel purposefully leaves the `NULL` address + some amount of space unmapped (maybe a few KB, maybe a few MB). Your instruction pointer will probably still go to 0, but as soon as the CPU tries to fetch an instruction from that address, **KABOOM**.

Comment: I've checked the optimization issue, the compiler did not "make a fuss" over it...

Comment: Oh, it was you all along... didn't even notice that... thanks :)